# Abducted children, psychic training

Tags: story-identification, novel, psychic

Does anybody know of a novel available late 80's/early 90's called something like 'KEEPER OF THE CHILDREN'?

The plot follows the efforts of a man to rescue an abducted child from a cult who have psychic powers.

He manages to find somebody to train him to develop psychic powers himself so as he can take on the leader of the group. He does this by having an 'out-of-body experience' and at one point while doing this assumes the body of a cat which he then engages in a fight with the leader (who has also assumed the body of a cat). The man, on returning to his real body notices cuts on his torso where the cat would have been scratched during the fight.

Other details include the man spending hours, day after day with an inverted jar on the floor in front of him. Inside the jar is a piece of paper folded in quarters, re-opened and balanced on a pin. The object of the exercise is for the man to cause the paper to spin by the power of thought. He does this and the next day is a bowling ball in a rack. He is meant to move the ball from one end of the rack to the other by thought. He eventually manages to do this, smashing the rack with the ball as a climactic moment before he sets off to do battle with the leader.

There are other sketchy details which may or may not be perfect so I'll omit them for now until I hear from some of you...hopefully!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsure if you're asking for identification of the novel or if it's available.  Appears you remember the name correctly.  Amazon has a [Keeper of the Children](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380452030) available in used versions.  There's a posted review that talks about a father attempting to get his daughter back from a cult leader with supernatural (psychic ?) talents including the ability to animate inanimate objects.

This [link](http://jasondeanbooks.blogspot.com/2013/06/great-forgotten-thrillers-3-keeper-of.html) has some story fragments that might confirm if this is the correct book. The daughter is a 14 year old named Renni; it's a cult of beggars led by a Tibetan monk named Kheim.  Kheim has the ability to astral project and to place his consciousness in inanimate objects and small animals at will.

Comment: Total awesomeness...

Comment: I should say more... I didn't realise enter would send the comment as opposed to insert a blank line...

Ah, and shift enter keeps me in this box!

Okay, now to the real point of this comment. Stan, thank you for that. I can't think why a search for 'Keeper Of The Children' didn't work for me, perhaps I hadn't narrowed my search to Amazon alone.

Anyway, this is exactly the book I was thinking about. It is amazing after over 25 years to have this amount of detail to refresh my memory.